# Why would cp not update the contents of a directory when employed?

Tags: linux, macos, cp

I have some PHP code I'm moving from a development directory to the webserver directory on OS X (Snow leopard).

I noticed something quirky I didn't understand with cp. I wrote a deployment script and noticed that when I run:

```
sudo cp -rf phpfun "/Library/Webserver/Documents/phpfun"
```

The command runs without an issue, but doesn't overwrite the files inside of the directory (namely index.php).

But if I run:

```
sudo cp -rf phpfun "/Library/Webserver/Documents/"
```

Everything is written as expected. What's the deal here? What is cp doing in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, it's copying the `phpfun` directory *inside* of `/Library/Webserver/Documents/phpfun`, meaning you end up with `/Library/Webserver/Documents/phpfun/phpfun`.  Probably not what you want.

The [`cp(1)` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) has all of the information you might need about what's going on and why.